# Make android USB-OTG as serial port device

Tags: android, linux, serial-port, usb, device

We're trying to re-build android system for new functions on USB-OTG port.

For most android phones, PC may recognize it's OTG port as an USB disk.

I want modify the linux kernel or android framework, so as to make the PC recognize OTG as an tty serial device.

Any suggestion for this issue? Thank you!